# How can I resize this map?

Tags: html, dictionary, resize, weather

http://www.weather.com/weather/map/interactive/44047?animation=true

I am trying to resize the div.wx-imap-pane.wx-module to height: 346px; width: 1727px; using greasemonkey and can't seem to get it to change.

I tried

```
div#div.wx-imap-pane.wx-module,
div#div.wx-imap-pane.wx-module > {
  width: 450px !important;
  height: 85px !important;
}
```

I have no idea what I'm really doing...

Answer (score 0):

The !important tags always is written last.
Try this, if it doesn't work, IDK what is wrong. ;)

```
.wx-imap-pane.wx-module {
  width: 450px;!important
  height: 85px;!important
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the web was set a global value for this div with JS you can't do anything. :(

Comment: `code<div class="wx-imap-pane wx-module" data-now-gmt="1372976074009" data-cmid="0009" data-cmpid="0001" data-clienthost="t.imwx.com"; data-profiler="" data-basemapoverride="" data-zoomoverride="7" data-layersoverride="0039" data-latoverride="41.738663" data-lonoverride="-80.7698" data-pagecode="imap-local" data-animation="false" style="height: 752px; width: 1371px;">code` Would there be a way to force the width to 1727px in this code?